# How to write mv command that will work as cron job

Tags: bash, mv

I'm running Centos 7. I need to have a cron job that moves everything from /media/tmp to /media/tv except the .grab and Transcode folders. Yesterday I thought that the following worked, but today it moves the Transcode folder as well.

```
mv -n /media/tmp/*!(Transcode)!(.grab) /media/tv/
```

I've found that the above does not work as a cron job as the '(' causes and error. I learned that I needed to escape those, but now I get

```
mv: cannot stat ‘/media/tmp/!(Transcode)!(.grab)’: No such file or directory
```

My current attempt at a bash script is

```
#!/bin/bash

mv -n '/media/tmp'/*!\(Transcode\)!\(.grab\) '/media/tv/'
```

My understanding is that the * is the problem, but using either ' or " on the file path doesn't seem to fix it like that post I found said it would.

Any ideas on how to get this to work correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to use [extglob](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob#extglob), which may not be enabled for cron. I would avoid that option entirely, iterating over the glob with a negative `!` regex match.

```
for file in /media/tmp/*; do
  [[ ! "$file" =~ Transcode|\.grab$ ]] && mv -n "$file" /media/tv/
done
```

Comment: youre closer but right now it'd still match names like `theTranscoder` or `foo.grab`. The RE needs to be `^(Transcode|\.grab)$`

Comment: I think it's reasonable to assume that `.grab` is an extension; OP's attempt with extglob doesn't indicate whether Transcode is a partial match. Good points though

Comment: I'm just going by her saying `except the .grab and Transcode folders` and so assuming she really does have directories of those names. Who knows though, no sample input strikes again...

Comment: Yes, Transcode and .grab are both directories that were created by Plex. The long story is that the commercial removal doesn't work if I record on the SMB share and I don't have much local storage. So I need to move the files once the recording is complete. This code worked. Thank you @vintnes

Comment: I spoke too soon. I need to be able to move directories that have a spaces in the name. When I try to move 'Steve (2017)' I get ```mv: cannot stat ‘/media/tmp/Steve’: No such file or directory
mv: cannot stat ‘(2017)’: No such file or directory ```

Comment: It looks like to deal with the spaces issue $file need to be "$file". vintnes, could you make that edit please?

Comment: **ALWAYS** quote your variables unless you **need** to leave them unquoted to achieve some specific purpose. See https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes.

Comment: Good catch; made fix

Answer (score 1):

I'd just do it as something simple like (untested):

```
mkdir -p /media/tv || exit 1
for i in /media/tmp/*; do
    case $(basename "$i") in
        Transcode|.grab ) ;;
        * ) mv -n -- "$i" /media/tv ;;
    esac
done
```

Comment: The /media/tv already exists, so I won't need the first line. For some reason it still moved the Transcode folder. The code that vintnes posted worked, so I'll just use that.

Comment: Then your "Transode" directory ("folder" is a Windows term btw, UNIX has "files" and "directories") isn't actually named "Transcode" as my code ensures the name is an exact string match while vintness' just looks for the string "Transcode" anywhere in the name.

Comment: ```$ ls -la
total 0
drwxr-xr-x. 4 plex plex 36 May  2 05:10 .
drwxr-xr-x. 6 root root 54 May  1 03:49 ..
drwxr-xr-x. 2 plex plex  6 May  2 03:00 .grab
drwxr-xr-x. 3 plex plex 22 Jan  7 05:59 Transcode``` Sorry, code doesn't seem to post well in the comments.

Comment: right, formatted text needs to go in questions or answers. I see the issue though - $i is the full path to the file not just the name of the file. I updated my answer.